# Gulp one file save to multiple files

Tags: npm, gulp

I have one file with 2 different localizations, I need to save each localization to own file.

I get file by src, at the next pipe I get 2 different locales, how can I made some sort of "forEach()" and gulp.dest() for each one with own file settings?

I've got in one file

```
<locale lang="en">Some EN info</locale>
<locale lang="de">Some DE info</locale>
```

I need this

en.txt =>
Some EN info

de.txt =>
Some DE info

Comment: If someone will interested in this, I get rid from gulp and did everything with node & fs package.